# Page loading and state dependency between different components

Tags: react-redux

I am building an application using React-Redux + React Router.
So, if user enters https://my-website.com/teams, I want to present him Teams page.

Lets suppose that my app consists of 2 components: Header and TeamsScreen.
I need to load user data to display Header.
I need to load user data & teams data to display TeamsScreen.

What is the right way to achieve it according to Best Practices?

What I have done so far:

1) Introduced a new component, lets name it AuthenticatedUser

```
render() {
    if(!this.props.userData)
       return (
           <Loader/>
       );

    return (
      <div>
        <Header userData={this.props.userData}/>
        <TeamsScreen userData={this.props.userData}/>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Which loads user data on componentDidMount.
If user data is null, it displays loader. If it's not null, it renders Header and TeamsScreen.

2) I give user data as property to Header. I give user data as property to TeamsScreen.

3) On componentDidMount in TeamsScreen I load teams data.
If teams data is null, I display loader for TeamsScreen. Otherwise I display TeamsScreen.

It seems working, but...In case of slow internet and/or slow database here is how it looks like:

1) There is a big loader for whole page while user data gets loaded.

2) As soon as it gets loaded, I display a header and loader gets moved a bit down till teams data is loaded and I can display TeamsScreen.

I have an uncomfortable feeling that I am doing something wrong.
Please correct me.

Thank you in advance!
Any hints / links to articles will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you should use redux. All code related to fetch data from server will be in actions which which can first start spinner and in turn dispatch another action which will hide spinner and set your data once data returned from server.